# importing map data into tableau

Tags: mapping, tableau-api

I'm new to Tableau and have a spreadsheet of census tracks and geolocation data. I would like to know how to import the data into into Tableau map. The GEOID10 data is paired with custom economic data, all on the same row. Where can I learn more about how to do this? Below is a sample of two rows from the data or you

GEOID10,             Total_Employed

06011000500,              2050

you can also see a sample of the data here https://www.dropbox.com/s/bgnxf9my3cmdniu/sample-city.xlsx?dl=0
Thank you!!

Comment: Can you explain a little bit better what GEOID10 is? What kind of geolocation data is it?

Comment: i believe is a census track data

Comment: Well, then unless Tableau recognize this kind of code (which I don't think is the case), you're going to need to relate those Ids to something Tableau recognize, such as city, state, country names, Zip codes, or even Latitude and Longitude